# Dynamic handler assignment in useEffect does not show update state in the handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, use-effect

Here is my example:

```
const App = () => {
  const [elements, setElements] = useState<{ text: string; onClick: () => any }[]>([])

  useEffect(() => setElements([
    {
      text: 'Click me',
      onClick: handleClick,
    }
  ]), []);

  const handleClick = () => {
    // I want to do something with elements here
    console.log(elements); // logs []
  }

  // Currently updated elements
  console.log(elements);

  return (
    <>
      {elements.map((e, i) => (
        <button key={i} onClick={e.onClick}>
          {e.text}
        </button>
      ))
      }
    </>
  )
};
```

I marked problematic part of the code with comment. Can someone explain why is this not working? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is the working sandbox of the above code: https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-shirley-ds78o?file=/src/App.js


You need to pass your state inside your dependency array inside useEffect.

useEffect(() => setElements([
    {
      text: 'Click me',
      onClick: handleClick,
    }
  ]), [elements]);

Comment: That causes infinite rendering loop :/

Answer (score 0):

Your component's `handleClick` function will have many `handleClick` functions declared within it throughout its "lifetime". Each time your component re-renders (and on the initial mount), you're re-defining your handleClick function. This is because each re-render causes your component's body to run again. Each time your `handleClick` function is defined, it "remember"s the variables defined within its surrounding scope at the time it was defined, such as the `elements` array. This idea of where a function can access the variables defined within its scope that it was defined in is called a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

In your code, your `useEffect` is saving the "first version" of your `handleClick` function that was created on the initial mount of your component. At that point your `elements` state was empty and so that version of your `handeClick` function will use the empty version of the `elements` array in subsequent re-renders. This is because, in future renders when `elements` does have values, your object within `elements` will hold a `handleClick` function that refers back to the original `handleClick` function (which only knows about the empty `elements` array).

I'm not sure if I would advise storing functions in state, as it can lead to issues like you're getting. Instead, I would suggest removing the `onClick` property from your objects and passing your `e` element from the `.map()` callback into `handleClick` (that is if you need to use `e` specifically). If you do this, then `handleClick` will be the same one as defined for the current render you're on, which will allow you to access `elements` correctly. Or if you really want, you can pass `elements` through and not rely on the value from the surrounding scope that it was defined in (however, depending on your actual use for this, there might be a more react-y way of doing this):

```js
const {useEffect, useState} = React;
const App = () => {
  const [elements, setElements] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => setElements([
    {
      text: 'Click me',
      onClick: handleClick,
    }
  ]), []);

  const handleClick = (elements) => {
    console.log(elements);
  }

  // Currently updated elements
  console.log(elements);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {elements.map((e, i) => (
        <button key={i} onClick={() => e.onClick(elements)}>
          {e.text}
        </button>
      ))
      }
    </React.Fragment>
  )
};
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @blackeenz no worries, if you feel as though this answers your question you can mark it (or any future answers that answer your question) as "answered" by clicking the grey checkmark in the top-left of the answer